# Showcase view in javascript application

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I need to create step by step showcase in my ASP.NET MVC application like is done in Android by ShowcaseView (https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView).

Do you know any javascript framework which done something familiar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe another tour like framework will help you.

Take a look to

http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

http://blog.tommoor.com/crumble/

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small single-file based script that ports ShowcaseView to client-side

[image]

Repo: https://github.com/nodegin/Showcase.js

Answer (score 1):

[showcaser](https://github.com/latitudegeo/showcaser) is a Material Design inspired showcase view for the web. Demo [here](https://latitudegeo.github.io/showcaser/).

[image]